# Raised non-Lorentz index notation

Tags: linear-algebra, smooth-manifolds, general-relativity

In several papers (An: https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.00118, equation (1.5), as well as papers by Klainerman, Rodnianski, and Luk on singularity formation in GR), one introduces a frame $e_a$ to spheres $S_{u, \bar u }$ of a double null foliation. They then write $e^a$ but don't define this; so my question is, what does this notation mean?

Since the $a$ is not a spacetime coordinate index, but rather a label, it is not the usual "raising an index" of general relativity, to my knowledge. I would guess it still means the same thing, in that $e^a$ is the covector which is the metric dual to $e_a$, but I was wondering if someone could confirm this, or give a reference where this is mentioned explicitly? The other likely option I can think of is that $e^a$ is the "linear dual" to $e_a$, i.e. the covector which evaluates to 1 on $e_a$ and zero on $e_b$ for $b \neq a$. Or perhaps another option is that it is just $e_a$, and we have raised an index so that a sum is implicit in the expression $e^a e_a (R)$ where $R$ is a scalar function.

Comment: From the first equation in page 10:
$$\Delta R = e^ae_a(R)$$
I'm tempted to say that they are defining $e^a=g^{ab}e_b$, since the Laplacian usually is $\Delta f=g^{ab}\partial_a\partial_b f$. See if that makes sense in your context.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz: I think this makes sense, though in general you have Christoffel symbol terms (i.e. $\Delta f = g^{ab}\partial_a \partial_b f +$ lower order terms). But since the $e_a$ are an ONB at each point, we can choose coordinates where they are the coordinate partials, and such that the Christoffel symbols vanish, and then we get $\Delta R = g^{ab}\partial_a \partial_b R = \sum e_a e_a (R)$. So I think this makes sense as the interpretation. Thank you! I'll leave the question open in case anyone knows of previous papers or general relativity resources talking about this notation.